# I cannot connect to mysql docker container from windows host machine

Tags: mysql, windows, docker, containers, connection

I search many topics and this question seems to be a duplicate but I still can't solve my problem with other answers. I run a MySQL docker container on windows 10 and expose it on port 5036, it's running fine and I can interact with this container through CLI on docker desktop. But when I try to connect via MySQL workbench and some others like HeidiSQL..., it both get the same error: Lost connection to server. I wonder if it's possible to connect to MySQL docker container from windows host machine via MySQL workbench?

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "2.5.0"

networks:
    laravel:

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: nginx
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - D:/dev/:/var/www/html
            - ./nginx/inmapzx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/inmapzx.conf
        depends_on:
            - php81
            - php74
            - php56
            - mysql8
            - mysql56
        networks:
            - laravel
    php74:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_php74
        container_name: php74
        volumes:
            - D:/dev/test3:/var/www/html/test3
        ports:
            - "9074:9000"
        networks:
            - laravel
    php56:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_php56
        container_name: php56
        ports:
            - "9056:9000"
        networks:
            - laravel
    php81:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile_php81
        container_name: php81
        ports:
            - "9081:9000"
        networks:
            - laravel
    mysql8:
        image: mysql:8.0.29
        container_name: mysql8
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "4036:3036"
        volumes:
            - ./mysql8:/var/lib/mysql
            - D:/dev/databases:/dumpfiles
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        networks:
            - laravel
    mysql56:
        image: mysql:5.6
        container_name: mysql56
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
            - "5036:3036"
        volumes:
            - ./mysql56:/var/lib/mysql
            - D:/dev/databases:/dumpfiles
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        networks:
            - laravel
```

This is the result when I run docker ps command:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS       PORTS                                         NAMES
9e58528b4174   nginx:stable-alpine   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 hours ago    Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                          nginx
eed1181295c6   mysql:8.0.29          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 hours ago   Up 3 hours   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4036->3036/tcp   mysql8
598e47fcde56   mysql:5.6             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 hours ago   Up 3 hours   3306/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5036->3036/tcp              mysql56
0fbc2feb6acb   laraveldocker_php56   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   2 days ago     Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:9056->9000/tcp                        php56
4d39b16f0113   laraveldocker_php81   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   2 days ago     Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:9081->9000/tcp                        php81
8b1bcfc385d6   laraveldocker_php74   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   2 days ago     Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:9074->9000/tcp                        php74
```

[This is my container running status on docker desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsjv7.png)

[This is what i got when trying to connect via MySQL Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax9PA.png)

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  This should include the actual text of your `docker run` command or `docker-compose.yml` file directly in the question.  Please include these details directly in the question and not behind links, and as plain text and not images.

Comment: Try using `host.docker.internal` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Hackerman I've already tried this but still got the same error: "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0"